# In Salesforce Apex code or in trigger code can we check if all my validations on the on Case Object or on Custom object passes

Tags: apex, trigger, validation-rule

In Salesforce Apex code or in trigger code can we check if all my validations on the on Case Object or on Custom object passes ?

In my current implementation, although validation Rule is Failing, still case is getting created. Case and Transaction object has Master-Detailed relationship. So Case is parent and Transaction is child.

Here validation rule is on the Transaction object, here my case is creating first and then Transaction object is creating. How can I restrict to create the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take help of `database.savepoint`

You can do something like

```
Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
try{
    insert parent;
    insert child;
}
catch(exception ex){
    Database.rollback(sp);
}
```

If anything goes wrong it will rollback to initial stage and will not create case record.

[Transaction Control](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_transaction_control.htm)

Comment: Thanks it working fine. I had just need to tweak my code. Please upvote the question

Comment: @JavaSystem if this works for you then you can accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks ! Some changes still needed in your code to avoid the Cross Reference Null